# How to trigger GHA when PR is reopened

Tags: github-actions, cicd

I'm trying to run a GitHub Action every time a PR is opened or reopened. The GHA triggered on opening works fine.
The GHA triggered by the reopening should run some checks and wait for some minutes before letting the "normal" installation steps reinstall the software, otherwise there's a race condition: the deletion step takes a while, meanwhile the reinstallation step sees that everything is still installed, and happily exits; after a while the deletion is finished, and the state of the installation is broken because no software is installed once the PR is reopened.

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, reopened]

jobs:
  wait-on-pr-reopening:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.event.pull_request.reopened == true
    steps:
      - name: Wait for deletion to complete before proceeding with reinstallation
        run: |
          # here there's some logic to check that the GHA that runs when PR is closed is done

  install-app:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: |
        # here goes the normal installation GHA that should be executed at PR reopening too,
        # but only after the deletion is completed
```

The problem is that the if condition `if: github.event.pull_request.reopened` (I tried with both `== true` and without) is always skipped.

Is that the correct value to filter on?

Is there another way to synchronize the state when reopening a PR?

Comment: A google search for [`"github.event.pull_request.reopened"`](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22github.event.pull_request.reopened%22) only finds [this repo](https://github.com/jenningsloy318/redfish_exporter/blob/master/.github/workflows/build.yml), where all GHA were skipped. :/

Comment: You can use `echo '${{ toJson(github) }}'` in a separate step to figure out whether these values are present or not.

Comment: Example: `if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'reopened' }}`

Comment: Your suggestion worked perfectly! If you make it into a answer I'll accept it (feel free to copy what I already posted below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [`pull_request`](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request) event payload, there's this `action` field that you can use to achieve that. Also, if you want to filter on the specific event, you can use [`github.event_name`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) to do that.

Combining above will give you something like this to enable/disable a job/step based on `pull_request` event and its action `reopened`:

```yaml
if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'reopened' }}
```

Currently, the workflow in your question only has `pull_request` trigger so you can skip `github.event_name` altogether and that should work too:

```yaml
if: ${{ github.event.action == 'reopened' }}
```

But, do this if and only if your workflow won't have any other event.

Answer (score 0):

There's indeed no variable at `github.event.pull_request.reopened`, so that was probably being evaluated as `null` and the step skipped.

@azeem's suggestion worked like a charm instead:

```yaml
if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'reopened' }}
```

I had to move the step into the main job because I needed the condition to run before the main installation step, not in parallel

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, reopened]

jobs:
  install-app:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Wait for deletion to complete before proceeding with reinstallation
        if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'reopened' }}
        run: |
          # here there's some logic to check that the GHA that runs when PR is closed
          # is done, with a timeout and a `exit 1` after some attempts.

      - run: |
        # here goes the normal installation GHA that should be executed at PR reopening
        # too, but only after the deletion is completed
```